# How do I put multi-line text on both sides of a brace?

Tags: braces

I want a curly left-bracket with three lines and the behind the bracket two lines, see pictures. I only got one line behind which is continued under the bracket when the paper is ended. How do I do that? (Don't notice about the different size of the text.)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

This was done inside an equation with two `tabular`s

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left.
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      text 1 \\
      text 2 \\
      text 3
    \end{tabular}
  \right\}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    More text \\
    more text
  \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `\text` isn't really required here. The content of a `tabular` environment is set in text mode even if the `tabular` appears in math mode.

Answer (score 6):

an alternative with use of the `rcases` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{rcases}
      \text{text} 1 \\
      \text{text} 2 \\
      \text{text} 3
    \end{rcases}
  \quad
  \begin{tabular}{l}
     More text \\
     more text
  \end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\left.
\Centerstack[l]{Text Part 1\\ Text 2\\Text 3}
\right\}
\qquad
\Centerstack[l]{More text\\and more text}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another very simple solution, with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray,,multirow, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{blockarray}{c\}\BAmultirow{1.5cm}}
    \bigstrut[t] \text{text} 1 & More text\\
      \text{text} 2 & more text\\
      \text{text} 3\bigstrut[b]
    \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]